# Validate list of last names of Hotel Guests according to the corresponding first name in a text file in Python

Tags: python, string, list, validation

I have a text file called listofhotelguests.txt where hotelguests are stored line by line with their first names separated by && as a delimiter. Can someone explain how I can have my Python program read it so it associates john with doe, ronald with macdonald, and george with washington?

My expected outcome I'm hoping for is if I prompt the user for their lastname to make sure their a valid guest on the list, the program will check it against what it has in the file for whatever the firstname they entered earlier was.

So if someone enters george as their first name, the program retrieves the line where it has george&&washington, prompts the user to enter their lastname and if it doesn't match what it has, either say it matches or doesn't. I can figure the rest out later myself.

Assuming there is nobody with the same names.

I know I have to split the lines with &&, and somehow store what's before && as something like name1 and whats after && as name2? Or could I do something where if the firstname and lastname are on the same line it returns name1 and password1?

Not sure on what to do. Python is one of my newer languages, and I'm the only CS student in my family and friend groups, so I couldn't ask anybody else for help. Got nowhere by myself.

Even just pointing me in the direction of what I need to study would help immensely.

Thanks

Here's what the text file looks like:

```
john&&doe
ronald&&macdonald
george&&washington
abraham&&lincoln
```

Here's some pseudocode:

```
listoffirstnames = []
listoflastnames= []

with open ("listofhotelguests.txt") as guestlist:
    for line in guestlist 
    listoffirstnames.append()
    listoflastnames.append()

while True: 
    firstname = input("Please enter your firstname")

    if (firstname in listoffirstnames):
        print("Hello" ,firstname)
        break

    else:
        print("Sorry, you weren't in the list. Please try again")

while True:
    print("Hello " + firstname + " please enter your last name.")
    lastname = input("Enter lastname to verify guest status: ")

    if (lastname in listoflastnames):
        print("Welcome back!" + firstname + lastname) 
        break
    else: 
        print("Sorry, the lastname was entered wrong")
```

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) is not a valid SO question. This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```py
first_names = []
last_names = []

with open("bruh.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        name = line.strip().split("&&")
        first_names.append(name[0])
        last_names.append(name[1])

print(first_names)
print(last_names)
```

Basically, `strip()` removes any pesky unwanted spaces on either end, and the `split()` function allows you to split a string based on the parameter, here `&&`. So `name` ends up storing the first and last name as a list, and you can access them through subscripts.

---

That said, a long-term better solution would be to store both the first and last names together as a list, inside a bigger list of all names. For example,

`names = [['john', 'doe'], ['firstname', 'lastname'], ...]`

For that you can use this:

```py
names = []

with open("bruh.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        name = line.strip().split("&&")
        names.append(name)

print(names)
```

Which outputs: `[['john', 'doe'], ['ronald', 'macdonald'], ['george', 'washington'], ['abraham', 'lincoln']]`

Admittedly, this does require more code to access all first and last names separately, but as I said, the convenience of having both parts of the name as part of a single list of names is a better long term approach.